# SecItemAdd not prompting for Touch ID

Tags: ios, touch-id

I have an odd problem with SecItemAdd() that seems to vary between iOS 8 and 9. For iOS 8, saving something to the secure enclave will prompt for Touch ID authentication (unless I have specified kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI to be @YES). This is what I would expect. However, on iOS 9, I never seem to get a Touch ID authentication on SecItemAdd.

I realize that between 8 and 9 there was a change to the attributes, and kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI is now deprecated in favour of kSecUseAuthenticationUI, but regardless of whether I omit kSecUseAuthenticationUI, or specify it with @YES, I never get prompted.

What *should* SecItemAdd() do?

Here is the code snippet of what I am attempting:

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL;  
  SecAccessControlRef sacObject;  

  sacObject = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,  
       kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly,  
       kSecAccessControlUserPresence, &error);  

  NSDictionary *attributes =  
  @{  
    (__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,  
    (__bridge id)kSecAttrService: @"Zenbanx",  
    (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount: tokenKey,  
    (__bridge id)kSecValueData: [tokenValue dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],  
    /  
    (__bridge id)kSecUseNoAuthenticationUI: @NO,  
    (__bridge id)kSecUseAuthenticationUI: @YES,  
    (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessControl: (__bridge_transfer id)sacObject  
    };  

  OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) attributes, nil);
```

My goal is to have code that presents the same user interaction between iOS 8 and 9.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

kSecUseAuthenticationUI only takes kSecUseAuthenticationUIAllow, kSecUseAuthenticationUIFail and kSecUseAuthenticationUISkip. In your case you should use kSecUseAuthenticationUIAllow.